# Replace value if absent with a previous value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
id, test, date
1, A, 01/20/2020
1, B, 01/25/2020
1, C, 01/25/2020
1, A, 02/20/2020
1, B, 02/25/2020
1, C, NA
```

Since the date for C in the last row is NA I want to lookup any previous date of C and populate it in place of NA.

The resulting dataframe should be:

```
id, test, date
1, A, 01/20/2020
1, B, 01/25/2020
1, C, 01/25/2020
1, A, 02/20/2020
1, B, 02/25/2020
1, C, 01/25/2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window **`lag`** function with **`when otherwise`** to check if `NA` in `date` column then replace with last seen value..

**`Example:`**

```
val df=Seq(("1","A","01/20/2020"),("1","B","01/25/2020"),("1","C","01/25/2020"),("1","A","02/20/2020"),("1","B","02/25/2020"),("1","C","NA")).toDF("id","test","date")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1=df.withColumn("new_dt",to_date(col("date"),"MM/dd/yyyy"))
val w=Window.partitionBy("id","test").orderBy(desc("new_dt"))

df1.withColumn("date",when(col("date")==="NA",lag(col("date"),1).over(w)).otherwise(col("date"))).drop("new_dt").show()
//+---+----+----------+
//| id|test|      date|
//+---+----+----------+
//|  1|   A|02/20/2020|
//|  1|   A|01/20/2020|
//|  1|   B|02/25/2020|
//|  1|   B|01/25/2020|
//|  1|   C|01/25/2020|
//|  1|   C|01/25/2020|
//+---+----+----------+
```

---

**`In Pyspark`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("1","A","01/20/2020"),("1","B","01/25/2020"),("1","C","01/25/2020"),("1","A","02/20/2020"),("1","B","02/25/2020"),("1","C","NA")],["id","test","date"])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1=df.withColumn("new_dt",to_date(col("date"),"MM/dd/yyyy"))

#change partitionby,orderby as per requirement
w=Window.partitionBy("id","test").orderBy(desc("new_dt"))

df1.withColumn("date",when(col("date")=="NA",lag(col("date"),1).over(w)).otherwise(col("date"))).drop("new_dt").show()
#+---+----+----------+
#| id|test|      date|
#+---+----+----------+
#|  1|   A|02/20/2020|
#|  1|   A|01/20/2020|
#|  1|   B|02/25/2020|
#|  1|   B|01/25/2020|
#|  1|   C|01/25/2020|
#|  1|   C|01/25/2020|
#+---+----+----------+
```